# ImportError: No module named 'telebot'

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, zabbix, telegram-bot

Olá!

Estou configurando o bot para enviar alertas do Zabbix, fiz a instalação do Python e os módulos necessários:

```
sudo apt install python python-pip python-setuptools
```

Aí instalei a API do bot para usar no Zabbix:

```
python -m pip install --user pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Criei o script em **/usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts/** :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import telebot,sys

BOT_TOKEN='TOKENAQUI'
DESTINATION=sys.argv[1]
SUBJECT=sys.argv[2]
MESSAGE=sys.argv[3]

MESSAGE = MESSAGE.replace('/n','\n')
tb = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)
tb.send_message(DESTINATION,SUBJECT + '\n' + MESSAGE)
```

Alterei as permissões de execução:

```
sudo chmod +x telegram

sudo chown -R zabbix telegram
```

E ao testar o script no terminal ou no Zabbix o erro a seguir aparece:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts/telegram", line 2, in 
>       import telebot,sys ImportError: No module named 'telebot'

Tentei resolver instalando o módulo:

```
python -m pip install --user telebot
```

Instalar o módulo não resolveu, aí tentei usar o python3, então, pelo terminal funcionou, mas no Zabbix continua mostrando o mesmo erro, acabei voltando para o python.

Alguém sabe  que pode estar causando o problema?

Comment: Qual a versão retornada com `/usr/bin/env python --version` e com apenas `python --version`?

Comment: Nas duas é Python 2.7.12

Comment: Alguma razão específica de ter utilizado o `--user`? Sabe se o diretório faz parte da sua variável de ambiente `PATH`? Pode confirmar verificando o caminho com `python -c 'import site; print(site.USER_BASE)'` e `echo $PATH`.

Comment: O `--user` vi em um dos fórum que visitei enquant tentava resolver, onde dizia para tentar usando isso. Os diretórios da variável `PATH` são `/home/appliance/.local` e  `/home/appliance/bin:/home/appliance/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games` .

Comment: Já havia tentado antes instalar sem a opção `--user`? Também deu o erro?

Comment: Sim, havia dado erro também, mas posso tentar novamente

Comment: Não mudou, continua com o mesmo erro.

Comment: O módulo `telebot` aparece com `pip list`? Ou quando, dentro do terminal do python, você dá o comando `help("modules")`?

Comment: Ele só aparece dentro do terminal do Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver, usando o `python3`, mas dessa vez removi as outras versões do `python` completamente antes de instalar novamente, os passos foram os seguintes:

```
sudo python -m pip uninstall pyTelegramBotAPI
sudo apt remove python python-pip python-setuptools
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-six
sudo python3 -m pip install pyTelegramBotAPI six
sudo pip install six
```